# twilio studio call connect to outbound number fails

Tags: twilio, call, twilio-studio

In twilio studio ,I was trying to forward my call to my cell phone number [Studio Flow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9dpp.png)  , In twilio studio its quite easy.

My paid number is usa local number,I am trying to make international call.is it possible?

I am using connect call to widget.And I choose forward to single number,there is also option like SIM,SIP etc.

It seems the call doesn't forward to my cellphone,it just drops the call. Am I missing something here?Or its bug with twilio?

Thanks.
Note: I am using a paid USA (TX)  number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72) for specific errors, also check to make sure you have the proper [voice geographic permissions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180228-International-Voice-Dialing-Geographic-Permissions-Geo-Permissions-and-How-They-Work) enabled.

Comment: Its the issue with geo permisson, I am actually developing someone else's project,they invited me via email. When I am trying to change save after checking my desired country ,it says can not save change,Is it like I dont have permission as a developer to save change to geo permission settings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64596107/6198332 would you mind check this thread? is there any update on media attachment in flex? @Alan